# Datatables pagination with Elasticsearch

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, datatables

How can you setup pagination on Datatables with Elasticsearch? I've already populated the Datatables with Elasticsearch result but it's not rendering pagination properly.

[image]

clicking on the numbered links will yield same data

Here's my JS code:

```
var searchResultTable = $('#search-results').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "elasticsearch/",
    "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
});
```

Here's my `views.py` (An excerpt; I'm using Django):

```
def elasticsearch_result_json(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('search[value]', None)
    results = search_service.get_remittances_json(search_query)

    return JsonResponse(
        {
        'data': results
        }
    )
```

The pagination is now working correctly but the data the table is showing
is the same in all pages.
[image]
Here's my updated `views.py`:

```
def elasticsearch_result_json(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get('search[value]', None)
    results = search_service.get_remittances_json(search_query)
    total_records = search_service.get_total_count()

    return JsonResponse({
        'draw': request.GET.get('draw', 0),
        'recordsTotal': total_records,
        'recordsFiltered': len(results),
        'data': results,
    })
```

Comment: In the `request`, you will see the parameters relating to paging, sorting etc.  You need to use these in your query to handle paginination.. See [datatables.net/manual/server-side](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Comment: @markpsmith see edit. Thanks!

Comment: Paging is not working because you need to use the `start` and 'length' parameters in your query.

Comment: @markpsmith I'm having trouble doing what you said. I added `"displayStart": 10` and `"pageLength": 10` but the problem persists.

Comment: No, you need to get the datatables `start` and `length` parameters - in the same way as you do for `search` and `draw` - and use them in your SQL query to page the data.  Without this, you're just returning the same data on every time.